# Webrtc (simple-peer) how to reconnect

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc

I am using simple-peer for webrtc. I can't seem to find how to reconnect peers if say one of them is disconnected from the others. Is reconnection for webrtc possible? Without stun or turn server involved?

Comment: Without STUN/TURN your peers will only be able to connect to each other on the same local network.

Comment: It's a reconnection. A peer would still have the network details of other peers, assuming no change in IP. Would a reconnection works?

Comment: You can reconnect as you were connecting for the first time.

Comment: @twb how had you solved this problem?

Comment: Don't use webrtc for mobile. Last checked, It's not there yet. It can't get through most routers and firewall. I can't even connect 2 mobile phones in the same WiFi network at home.

Answer (score 0):

you need stun/turn to generate the different ice candidates possible to the peer and then add those candidates to offer/answer. So for the reconnection where offer and answer model is required you need stun/turn depending on peer network.